# Spring JPA Specification : How to sort on aggregate function using specification

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql, jpa-criteria

Error is thrown when we are trying to sort on aggregated column COUNT.

For Example : Requirement is to form below query using specification. But, it is not returning single entity as result. Rather, it's join of tables.

**Sort on SQL Query required using Specification** :

```
Select DISTINCT ss.studentId.name, ss.studentId.department , COUNT (DISTINCT ss.subjectId.id)" +
            "FROM SubjectStudent  ss " +
            "left outer join ss.studentId sd  " +
            "left outer join ss.subjectId su "+
            "GROUP BY  ss.studentId.cve, ss.subjectId.id " +
            "ORDER BY ss.studentId.department
```

So, here how can we sort on aggregate column COUNT using specification?

Comment: in sql you can directly use the selected column number.
e.g 
select name, count(*) from table group by name order by 2

Comment: how to implement using JPA Specification?

Comment: Solution : criteriaBuilder.having(<<Condition>>) whenever we want to put condition on aggregate functions using specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution : criteriaBuilder.having(<>) whenever we want to put condition on aggregate functions using specification